# Generate JS function in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I would like generate js function in loop, but I have problem. Please, can anybody tell that my thinking is right ? It's is possible to generate functions in loop?

```
var sortItems =
                    ["sortable11","sortable12","sortable13","sortable14","sortable15",
                    "sortable21","sortable22","sortable23","sortable24","sortable25",
                    "sortable31","sortable32","sortable33","sortable34","sortable35",
                    "sortable41","sortable42","sortable43","sortable44","sortable45",
                    "sortable51","sortable52","sortable53","sortable54","sortable55"];
                for ( key in sortItems) {
                    $(function(){
                        $('#' + sortItems[key]).sortable({
                            update: function(event, ui)
                            {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "fun/saveOrder.php",
                                    dataType: "text",
                                    data: 
                                        {
                                        key:$(this).sortable('toArray')
                                    },
                                    cache: false,
                                    beforeSend: function(){$('#updateResult').html('updating');},
                                    success: function(data){$('#updateResult').html(data);},
                                    error: function(data){$('#updateResult').html(data);}
                                })
                                recalculate();
                            }
                        })
                    })
                }
```

Comment: What is function `recalculate();`?

Comment: Is this a JS[H|L]int warning or do you actually have a problem with the code? If the latter, please add more details on your expected behavior and what happens.

Comment: $(function(){...}) is an alias for $(document).ready(function(){})  I'm quite sure it is not what you are looking for here

Comment: Use a common `[class]` rather than a bunch of similar `[id]`s

Comment: duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: and have a look at [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

It's prefectly fine to generate functions in loops in JavaScript, syntactically speaking.

It's not recommended though : if you have a large number of objects, generating lots of closures (this is what the anonymous functions you're creating are called) can be slow. But I doubt you'll be running into that.

Another reason why it's not recommended is that the `key` variable you're using inside your function is a reference to a `var` that's the *exact same variable*, *outside* of the closure, thus rendering your loop completely useless in practice. Maybe check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) out, it could help.

Without knowing more about the issue you're facing it's pretty hard to say more.

Answer (score 0):

If you first generate an array of DOM elements, you can drop the for-loop:

```
var sortItems = ["sortable11","sortable12","sortable13","sortable14","sortable15",
                    "sortable21","sortable22","sortable23","sortable24","sortable25",
                    "sortable31","sortable32","sortable33","sortable34","sortable35",
                    "sortable41","sortable42","sortable43","sortable44","sortable45",
                    "sortable51","sortable52","sortable53","sortable54","sortable55"],
sortElements = $.map(sortItems, function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
});

$(sortElements).sortable({
   // your options here
});
```

Also, your loop was doing `$(function() { ... }` at every iteration; it's only required once, so you can wrap it around above code (or move this code to the end of your `<body>` element.

Comment: Thanks for Your replies,
Jack Your solution work great, but I would like have a separate information in which sortable box elements was change position,

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generate/create functions in a loop. One of the ways it could be done:

```
var test = ['name','phone','address'];
var test2 = [];
$.each(test,function(k,v){ test2[k] = function(){alert(v)}});

test2[0]; //alerts 'name'
test2[1]; //alerts 'phone'
test2[2]; //alerts 'address'
```